# Compare class of an element and classes from another element

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a class of a menu element on certain page with `id="menuelement"` like `class="page_item page-item-10"` and class on the same of an element with `id="pagetitle"` like `page-item-10`.
Decimals can change in both classes and on diferent pages like page-item-11, page-item-13 etc.

I need to write out the statemen like

```
if ($('#pagetitle').attr('class')== $("#menuelement").has_some_class){
   // do something
}
```

IT seems to me regulare expression like `page-item-[0-9]+`  , but can not figure out how.

UPDATE

Now, when I found the relative class I want to do something, but "this" seems not to work

```
if (jQuery("#darbimenu").find('li').hasClass(jQuery('#pagetitle').attr('class'))){
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass("someclass");
        }
```

I want to set a class to parent of found div.  How to?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?:

```
if ($("#menuelement").hasClass($('#pagetitle').attr('class')))
```

Comment: I will be more precise. #menuelement is a parent ul for li's and one of those li's can have class as #pagetitle

Comment: .find('li') was the key!  Thank you Alex. I was beating my head on the wall, but it was super easy at the end :D

Comment: Only thing I cannot get trought - I cannot get the found li class to work with
if (jQuery("#darbimenu").find('li').hasClass(jQuery('#pagetitle').attr('class'))){
  jQuery(this).parent().addClass("fffffffffffffffffffffffff");
  }
(this) is not geting the corresponding object